# Flutter Display value in textfield

Tags: flutter, dart

I hope the title is enough to understand what my problem is, how do i display the value of button in TextField when it is clicked? thank you in advance whoever will help me to configure this problem.

```
                TextEditingController _controller;
                void initState() {
                _controller = new TextEditingController(text: '${formatCurrency.format(totalbet)}');
                }
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: globals.fontsize_28,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontFamily: "Nunito",
                  ),
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                          const Radius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
          
                )
```

button

```
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Container(
                  child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      text: "500",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: globals.fontsize_18,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (betbuttonstate[0] == false) {
                      betbuttonstate[0] = true;
                      totalbet = totalbet + betbuttonvalue[0];
                      totalmoney = totalmoney - betbuttonvalue[0];
                    } else {
                      betbuttonstate[0] = false;
                      totalbet = totalbet - betbuttonvalue[0];
                      totalmoney = totalmoney + betbuttonvalue[0];
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this inside `onPressed` method of the button

```
                  setState(() {
                    if (betbuttonstate[0] == false) {
                      betbuttonstate[0] = true;
                      totalbet = totalbet + betbuttonvalue[0];
                      totalmoney = totalmoney - betbuttonvalue[0];
                    } else {
                      betbuttonstate[0] = false;
                      totalbet = totalbet - betbuttonvalue[0];
                      totalmoney = totalmoney + betbuttonvalue[0];
                    }
                    _controller.text = '${formatCurrency.format(totalbet)}';
```

#### Your `initState` should look like this

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        new TextEditingController(text: '${formatCurrency.format(totalbet)}');
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean Set the text in onPressed?

Comment: in every button?

Comment: Checkout my updated answer. You just use `_controller.text = ` to assign new value in your `onPressed` method.

Comment: where i paste it? inside the Textfield?

Comment: Inside `onPress` of the `FlatButton`.

Comment: i am having error in `_controller.text` seems like it didnt detect

Comment: I am having error `The setter 'text=' was called on null.`

Comment: i have this `controller: _controller,` inside of my `TextField`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229523/discussion-between-rene-and-yobo).

Answer (score 1):

Change value by controller `_controller.text = newValue` in button's on press setState() like this.

```
onTap: (){
setState((){
_controller.text=newValue
});
}
```